# Yosemite Photos can't delete photos from iPhone

Tags: iphone, photos.app, import

I just updated my mac to the new Photos and I imported some images from my iPhone 6. My question is rather simple. Why I can't delete the imported images in my iPhone from Photos??? I was able to do that in the old iPhotos.

Running on version: 1.0.1 (215.65.0)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Photos you have an option to "delete items after import" near the imports buttons, in the top right corner

[image]

In Photos on the other corner I have "Open photos from this device checked"

[image]

Try to keep up to date Yosemite, Itunes and Photos. Also in Itunes when you connect your apple device in the Photos settings uncheck "Sync Photos"

[image]

After you have done all this. Restart your computer. and try again.

Comment: That is really strange... My Photos doesn't have that!! I updated my post with a pic please take a look!

Comment: I had to close the iCloud Photo Library sync from my iPhone.